# Combining variance reduction techniques

Tags: monte-carlo, blue

I'm looking for some reference on the combination of various variance reduction techniques, in particular a best linear unbiased estimator.  The only reference I have is McLeish - Monte Carlo Simulation & Finance. Thanks.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.frankfurt-school.de/clicnetclm/fileDownload.do?goid=000000429802AB4)?

Comment: I am not sure there is such a thing as the best linear unbiased estimator in Monte Carlo approximation. This is a statistical concept, while in Monte Carlo approximation of $I=\int h(x) p(x)\text{d}x$, a zero variance estimator is available, namely $I$ itself.

Comment: This is the reference I have: Theorem 37 (best linear combinations of estimators), page 34 of http://sas.uwaterloo.ca/~dlmcleis/s906/chapt4.pdf